# How to generate 1 click deployment for SQL Scripts across environments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to generate 1 click deployment for SQL Scripts across environments?

We have bunch of scripts which can be Alter Stored Procedure , Insert scripts for data configuration which are deployed periodically. At this moment, we are deploying the scripts manually executing the scripts.

Right now, we are planning for one click deployment which will automatically deploy the scripts across the environments.

Comment: You may want to look at a product like `https://flywaydb.org/`. Ultimately, I think this, as a Stackoverflow question is off-topic since this is almost definitely going to be a *"What product can I use to help with one-click deployment of SQL across many environments"*

Comment: Is there a way without depending on third party tools. In order to use third party tools, I need to get permission .. which is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure how would manage "one-click deployment" without a tool. What tool are you currently using?

Comment: Need not to be a tool, can we have a Batch script ?  To do one click deployment process

Comment: Like "Loop through this list of servers", "List through these `.sql` files and apply each .sql file to the server" type of thing? That seems reasonable. Might be nicer to develop in C# or something more robust for error handling and whatnot. But then why not install a tool on whatever computer you are running this on? Or do you need permission just to install on your comp (I totally get that).

Comment: I think.. we are making this more difficult.. i am looking on simple and easier way of deploying .. might be a simple batch script..

Comment: Sounds like you've got some development work to do!

Answer (score 1):

To my mind use **SQL Server Database Project** in Microsoft Visual Studio. You can develop all database objects like *tables, view, functions, stored procedure and every script*. And also import database schema from existing database. You can provide code for post deploy and every data configurations.

some benefits:

1. version and source control
2. develop all database objects
3. easy and automated deployment

and more benefits...

[How to: Create a New Database Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272677(v=vs.103).aspx)